# Spring Security In memory authentication not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I am trying to implement an in memory authentication using spring security with a predefined user id and password. i am using basic HTTP authentication and sending the user id and password combination as a Header in the form "userId:password" (for the sake of simplicity , i am ignoring the encoding of above mentioned header).

Below is one of the rest end point for which i am trying to implement spring security.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/course", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> addCourse(@RequestBody Course course) {
   return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponse>(new ApiResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), null), HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

Below is the junit test,using which i am trying to validate the spring security configuration

```
@Test
  public void testAddCourse() throws Exception {
    String inputJsonRequest = JacksonMapperUtil.convertObjectToJsonString(course);
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/course")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(inputJsonRequest)
        .header("jane_doe", "admin_password"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.statusCode").value(HttpStatus.OK.value()));
  }
```

Below is the websecurity config file,that i have configured.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("john_doe")
        .password("student_password")
        .authorities("ROLE_STUDENT_USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("jane_doe")
        .password("admin_password")
        .authorities("ROLE_OFFICE_ADMIN");
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("john_doe")
        .password("student_password")
        .authorities("ROLE_STUDENT_USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("jane_doe")
        .password("admin_password")
        .authorities("ROLE_OFFICE_ADMIN");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/course")
        .hasAuthority("ROLE_OFFICE_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/student")
        .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_OFFICE_ADMIN", "ROLE_STUDENT_USER")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
  }

  @Bean
  RestAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
    return new RestAccessDeniedHandler();
  }

  @Bean
  RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    return new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
  }
}
```

AuthenticationEntryPoint implementation class

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),
        "Authentication Failure-The user name and password combination is incorrect");
    OutputStream out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(out, response);
    out.flush();
  }
```

AccessDenied Handler implementation class

```
@Component
public class RestAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
  @Override
  public void handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AccessDeniedException e)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),
        "Authorization Failure-This user does not have the sufficient level of access");
    OutputStream out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(out, apiResponse);
    out.flush();
  }
```

The maven dependencies used:

Spring boot version - 2.2.1.RELEASE

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

The problem with the above configuration that i have noticed is that, the authentication of incoming request is not done, even if the request comprises of correct/in correct userId:password header value.
Can some one point out what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hope this helps https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a password encoder, either define the bean like;

```
@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

or type {noop} just before the password as below

```
.withUser("john_doe")
        .password("{noop}student_password")
```